# Upload document files using file api

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, fileapi

Iam using below code to upload files using jquery fileapi.Images uploading fine but documents(doc,xls) files are not uploading.In console it shows 'empty files'(wriiten in js code).Please help.

in images upload, test.php file is called but others it does not call this file.am i missing anything?

Header part

```
   <script> 
        FileAPI = {
            debug: false,
            pingUrl: false,
            staticPath: 'dist/'
        };
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/FileAPI.min.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

dist folder contains

```
FileAPI.flash.image.swf,
FileAPI.flash.swf,
FileAPI.min.js,
```

Javascript functions

```
function handleAllFileTypesSelect(evt)
{

     {

        var files = FileAPI.getFiles(evt);

        FileAPI.filterFiles(files,function(file, info) {
            image_mime = file.type;

            console.log(info);

            if (/doc|docx|pdf|txt|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|ods|zip|csv|/.test(file.type) && info) {

                return info.width >= 1 && info.height >= 1;
            } else {

                return file.size > 0;
            }
        },

        function(fileList, ignor) {

            if (ignor.length) {
                console.log('ignor length:' + ignor.length);
            }
            if (!fileList.length) {
                console.log('empty file list');
                return;
            }

            // do preview
            var fileList = FileAPI.filter(fileList, function(file) {
                return /doc|docx|pdf|txt|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|ods|zip|csv|/.test(file.type);
            });


            j = 0;

            FileAPI.each(fileList,function(imageFile) {
                FileAPI.upload({
                    url : 'test.php',
                    data : {
                        type : 'pdf',
                        file_prefix : 'image_',
                        file_length : fileList.length,

                    },
                    files : {
                        files : FileAPI.filter(fileList,function(file) {
                            return !/doc|docx|pdf|txt|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|ods|zip|csv|/.test(file.type);
                        }),
                        child_attachments : imageFile
                    },
                    complete : function(err, xhr) {
                        if (!err) {
                            if ((xhr.responseText).search(/ERROR: File/gi) == -1) {

                                var response_text_value = xhr.responseText;
                                response_text_value = response_text_value.replace(/\s/g,'');
                                alert(response_text_value);
                                //$('#ifileList').val(val + ','+ response_text_value);
                                //$('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                                                                                                                                });
                    FileAPI.Image(imageFile).preview(100, 75).get(function(err,image) {
                        if (err) {
                        } else {

                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        );
    } // else
}   

</script>
```

HTML

```
 `<form id="observation_form" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="test.php" enctype`="multipart/form-data">

        <span class="file-wrapper js-fileapi-wrapper" id="span-image"  style="position: relative;">
                          <input id="logo" name="child_attachments[]" data-preview_id="preview_list" type='file' accept="" multiple  />
                          <span class="button">Attachments</span>
                        </span>
        </form>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('logo').addEventListener('change', handleAllFileTypesSelect, false);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php
2. Invalid regular expression (always `true`), delete the last pipe.